# How to Change iframe every 10 sec

Tags: javascript, iframe

How to change iframe every 15seconds. I have wat to show content inside an iframe. I want to show it on a single box approximately of 310px in width. Please give me detailed code because I am total newbie to javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you mean by change?

Comment: *Please give me detailed code* That is not how you [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) in stackoverflow.

Comment: @mayuresh: Please do some research,try some code , use google and then , if you are still finding it difficult , post a question on SO with relevant code.

Comment: @Mayuresh still don't know what you mean by change! change the content?

Comment: @fGo Yes! I want to create a box where I can show dynamic content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your iframe has an ID 'myiframe':

```
var urls = [
'http://www.google.com',
'http://www.microsoft.com',
'http://www.yahoo.com',
'http://www.facebook.com',
];

setInterval(function() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);
    document.getElementById('myiframe').src = urls[rand];
}, 15000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/C6CK5/

Comment: So you mean in variable urls I need to put all those links of iframes & in body give one iframe an id [myiframe]  ?

Comment: see fiddle if you're that lazy to try it out yourself

Comment: ok I tried it but it shows an empty iframe

Comment: @Mayuresh The code is setting a timer to run a function every 15 seconds. Then it randomly chooses a URL from the array and sets it to the source of the iframe. But yeah - click the jsfiddle link to see it working.